# Server variable not recognized on Google Tag Manager with "HTML Custom" type tag

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to put a GTM container on my webpage, just to add scripts without modify html of my page (I will no longer have acces).

1)Currently, I just put the GTM code after , created a tag on my GTM account (tag type = GA), added UA-XXXXX-Y of my GA account : it's work, I can see visit from my GA acc.

2)Then, I tried to change the type of my tag created on GTM : I choose Custom HTML type, and I put the code given by GA (with correct UA)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-Y']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example.com']);
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

It's work too, I see visit from GA interface

3) I want to modify the code given by GA, especially add trackPageview with param (using server variable, here's my problem...)

So I just modified code that I used in 2), just adding :

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/Page1/$!{VAR}/Page2/$']);
```

and it doesn't work.

Did I do something wrong? Should I use macro?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serverside variables are not going to work with GTM (since the code is inserted via javascript  from a different server) so yes, a macro ist the way to go.

Create a data layer (a JSON var that is inserted after the opening body tag just before the GTM tag:

```
<script>
dataLayer = [{    
    'myVar': '{VALUE INSERTED BY SERVER }'

}];
</script>
```

Now you can access myVar as a macro in GTM ( "{{myVar}}" ):

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '{{myVar}}']);
```

This also works with the GA tag template in GTM (there is an option to insert a virtual url, you can use macros there).

Comment: I have to create my data layer(with all var) and add it directly on my code page, not with GTM so, that's right?

I just have another question, my var can have different value, depending the previous page, for example with my last exemple :

"_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '$!{VAR}/Page2/']);"

{VAR} can be "Paris" or "Cannes" or another value of my city list (6 possibilities), depending what the user choose on the previous page. How can I proceed?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) I'm not sure what you mean (you can set you server side variable according to the user's selection on the previous page, so I don't understand the problem - please clarify).

Comment: This is a travel booking site. Users have to choose a city, an agency and a product, and they arrived on the reservation page, which is the same for all product.
The actually GA code on the page is :

['b._trackPageview', '/City/$!{codeAgence}/Dispo/$!{product}']
and "codeAgence" and "product" are defined with the previous choice of the user. Because this reservation page is unique,I don't really know how I can set variable in a data layer like you say on your answer...
Theses server side variables were created only for GA code and to make the converting funnel easier to establish.